# Diodes in parallel reduce current compared to single measurement

Tags: led, diodes, semiconductors, photonics

I have a photonics integrated circuit with two quantum well diodes. (exact description below)

If I measure the IV curve for each individual diode I get pretty much the same curve for both. but if I measure the same IV curve for both diodes in parallel I get a lower IV curve than if I would add up both single measured diodes. The data is seen in the plot.

Edit:
(single measurement of 2 (blue) + single measurement of 4 (yellow))(green dashed) > parallel measurement of 2 and 4 (red)

(Blue and yellow data is each single SOA, green dashed is the both added up, red is the parallel measurement. The difference is seen in black dashed)

I would have expected it to be the same or even higher due to thermal run away but not much lower. Do you have any idea what the reason could be?

Thank you!

Edit: I added a drawing of the circuit. There are actually 5 diodes in total optically connected by a waveguide building a ring resonator. Number 2,3 and 4 have the same structure but 3 is smaller. 1 and 5 have also the same structure but different to the others.
For all measurements 1 and 5 are grounded and 3 is floating. For single measurements of 2 and 4 the other one is also grounded. The whole setup is passively cooled.

[image]

[image: Blue and yellow data is each single SOA, green dashed is the both added up, red is the parallel measurement. The difference is seen in black dashed.]

Comment: This is a photonic integrated circuit; is there any kind of coupling between the diodes? I don't know about them but aren't some kinds of interference effects possible?

Comment: Hi, I added a drawing of the structure. The diodes are coupled by waveguides as a ring resonator. So there is interference of light and some interaction between them but I cannot think of any reasons, why it should behave differently if I use two instead of 1 diode.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from you description what is going on because the graph does not match what you describe in the top paragraph.

There are a few things that could happen.

One is the current flows through both diodes equally. Each device would have to have a very similar IV curve. If so then you would get close to 1/2 of the current from the supply flowing through each device.

The other is the IV curves aren't match enough, significant current goes through one diode and not as much as the other. If this is happening you may need series resistance through both diodes to help match them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMvNzV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is shown in the data:
(single measurement of 2 (blue) + single measurement of 4 (yellow))(green dashed) > parallel measurement of 2 and 4 (red)

The diodes should be really similar. The IV curves look very similar.

I would have expected that if the current goes 1/2 each. Then the single currents should add up. If not, than the diode should heat up and the total current should increase but not decrease.

Comment: Are you measuring both dioes at the same time when they are in parallel? Or are you doing measurement at different times?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But if in parallel I have one measurement device for both diodes. It is the same I use for doing the single measurements.

Comment: Are you doing a 4 wire kelvin measurement?

Comment: No, I am actually using the integrated multimeter (for current and voltage) of the current source. I was already thinking that this might be off, but I would have expected it to either than be off for all measurements or show a higher current due to thermal run away.

Comment: What model for the multimeter?

Comment: It is a Teledyne DC Power Supply. It is used as a power supply but also measures the voltage and current with integrated multimeter.

Comment: I would suggest doing a 4 wire measurement. The leads could be causing error

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot repeat the measurements, I do not have the device anymore. But I will look into it and see if I could make that work for me to explain this difference.

Comment: One problem is you have a large amount of resistance from the cables, it will be difficult or impossible to model the cable resistance with the data you have.